# rewrite and redirect in asp net core 2 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing a website using ASP net core 2 MVC and using rewrite rules to change the request to another address.

These codes are added into my codes

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^.*maplayer(.*)", 
    "https://new-server/geoserver/wms$1", true);
app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

However, these codes don't work for me. Then I try using `AddRedirect` which is working as expected.

Are there any constrains about `AddRewrite` in asp net core?

Comment: Are you aware that `RewriteOptions.AddRewrite` will not cause another round trip and  it is solely done on the server side? However, `AddRedirect` will. Therefore, if `AddRedirect` works then the client is doing something and you need to do the same thing in `AddRewrite` so it can work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you suggest me how to do "same thing"?

Comment: Sorry I cannot because I do not have access to core but basically what I am saying is that you need to inspect the request for a redirect and see if it is the same as what you are doing in code. Not an expert with this feature so I cannot help further. But that is where I would start.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thank you very much for your help. Will check it and wait for other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to rewrite to an external link, you need to configure ARR and reverse proxy to achieve that. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing